# Get access to class.field_1 combining its property name with string "field_" and "1"

Tags: kotlin

Suppose I have a data class `Foo` with properties like:

```
field_1
field_2
....
field_10
```

An object of this class was created like

```
val foo = Foo(1, 2,...10)
```

For some reason I want to get access to properties using something like this:

```
//here is correct
val fieldNumber = someFunToCalculateFieldNumber()
val combinedFooField = "field_$fieldNumber"

//here is wrong
val value = foo.combinedFooField
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This is called reflection. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html But in a case like this, I'd suggest using `varargs` or a single `List` property so you can access the elements without resorting to reflection.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use Kotlin Reflection module

from :

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.4.0-rc

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0-rc</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
 </dependency>
```

**then :**

```
package org.example

data class Hello(val a: Int, val b: Int, val c: Int, val d: Int) {
    fun getFields() = Hello::class.java.declaredFields.withIndex().map {
        "${it.index},${it.value.name}"
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   val h = Hello(1,2,3,4)
    for (field in h.getFields()) {
        println(field)
    }
}
```